# 3 links in sidebar moved to the right with dispaly flex and I don't know why

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create a sidebar for a website with 10 sidebar links. most of the links work with the css but 3 of these links moved to the right. all with a different margin. It is so strange. the problem comes with  aside .sidebar a {..} when I used display flex in it 3 of the items in the sidebar moved. can anyone help?

[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1.8rem;
  grid-template-columns: 14rem auto 23rem;
}

aside {
  height: 100vh;
}

aside .top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
}

aside .logo {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}

aside .logo img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

aside .close {
  display: none;
}


/* sidebar */

aside .sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 86vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 3rem;
}

aside .sidebar a {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 3.7rem;
}

aside .sidebar a:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <aside>
            <div class="top">
                <div class="logo">
                    <img src="logo.png" alt="">
                    <h2>NA <span class ="danger">AM</span></h2> 
                </div>
                <div class="close" id="close-btn">
                <span class="matial-icons-sharp">close</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sidebar">
                <a href="#" class ="active">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">grid_view</span>
                <h3>Dashboard</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#" >
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">person outline</span>
                <h3>Klanten</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">receipt long</span>
                <h3>Bestellingen</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">insights</span>
                <h3>Analytics</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">mail outline</span>
                <h3>Berichten</h3>
                <span class="message-count">99</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">inventory</span>
                <h3>Producten</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">report_gmailerrorred</span>
                <h3>Klachten</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">settings</span>
                <h3>Instellingen</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">add</span>
                <h3>Product toevoegen</h3>
                </a>
                <a href="#">
                <span class="material-icons-sharp">logout</span>
                <h3>Uitloggen</h3>
                </a>
            </div>
        </aside>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think we will need to see the rest of your HTML (at least the sidebar) in order to diagnose the problem correctly; can you include it for us?

Comment: As your question sits currently, the issue you describe is non-reproducible. Please include the minimal amount of code to reproduce the issue and perhaps a screenshot of the issue and the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration for `grid-template-columns` did not leave enough room for the sidebar. Therefore there were overflow issues because of the grid specificity and especially cause there are no widths defined on any of the sidebar elements.

The grid before:

[image]

The grid after:

[image]

I also set your `display: flex;` directly on your `a` using `aside>.sidebar>a`. You did not include the [child combinator `>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) so it was setting those styles on all of those classes, not just the `a`. Lastly, you should have widths defined for your flex-items, or else the browser will assume their width based on content and you will end up with un-aligned content.  I also cleaned up other aspects of the HTML and CSS. Please see the snippet below for those changes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  width: 96%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  gap: 1.8rem;
  grid-template-columns: 23rem auto 23rem;
}

aside {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

aside .top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 1.4rem;
}

aside .logo {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}

aside .logo img {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}

aside .close {
  display: none;
}


/* sidebar */

aside .sidebar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 3rem;
}

aside>.sidebar>a {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  height: 3.7rem;
}


span,
h3 {
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 120px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <aside>
    <div class="top">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="logo.png" alt="">
        <h2>NA <span class="danger">AM</span></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="close" id="close-btn">
        <span class="matial-icons-sharp">close</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <a href="#" class="active">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">grid_view</span>
        <h3>Dashboard</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">person outline</span>
        <h3>Klanten</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">receipt long</span>
        <h3>Bestellingen</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">insights</span>
        <h3>Analytics</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">mail outline</span>
        <h3>Berichten<span class="message-count">&nbsp;99</span></h3>

      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">inventory</span>
        <h3>Producten</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">report_gmailerrorred</span>
        <h3>Klachten</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">settings</span>
        <h3>Instellingen</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">add</span>
        <h3>Product toevoegen</h3>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="material-icons-sharp">logout</span>
        <h3>Uitloggen</h3>
      </a>
    </div>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried it but now the links are really far apart from the icons

Comment: @JibbeMiddelbrink try removing the width and min-width from the span and h3. If that doesn't work I don't know what to tell you. You need to ask a more concise question.